# Will the joined field use an Index in MongoDB aggregation lookup query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

Example :

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

This  is  a  joined  operation  in Mongodb.

If  the **foreignField** has  an  Index, will it use the  Index ?

Also with the **localField**  field Index.

**Edit** :
add  the explain  with agg

```
> db.a.explain().aggregate([{ $lookup:{from: "b",localField: "b",foreignField: "b",as: "bs" }}])
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "test.a",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {

                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "b",
                "as" : "bs",
                "localField" : "b",
                "foreignField" : "b"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1571198359, 2),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1571198359, 2),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

It  doesn't  show the  details   for  `$lookup`.

Comment: You can try running the query plan using the `explain`. This will show if the query is using any existing indexes. You can do it like this: `db.orders.explain().aggregate( [ ... `

Comment: the  foreignField  in  $lookup can‘t Show those  details

Comment: Are there any indexes defined on the the two collections? Try the command, `db.collection.getIndexes()`.

Comment: You can specify the aggregation option `hint` ( e.g., `{ hint : { indexed_fld : 1 } }` ) to use an index. But, the indexed field is for the initial collection against which the aggregation is run. This is valid as of **MongoDB 4.0**. I was able see the IXSCAN on the query plan.

Comment: For example, the following query used / showed the index on `orders` collection's `item` field: `db.orders.explain().aggregate( [ { $lookup: ... } ], { hint: { item:1 } } )` .